# How do I create a basic database in postgresQL/pgadmin on Windows from scratch?

Tags: database, postgresql, pgadmin

I have installed postgresql and pgadmin and am attempting to set up a basic database for a project. My initial problem is:

- I'm not sure which tasks I need to complete in psql versus pgAdmin.
- I'm not sure what order domain/users/host/database name etc. need to be set up in. I don't think I have a database or server yet, but I'm not sure.
- I don't know how postgresql and pgadmin connect to eachother.

So far I have attempted to create a database and example table using the psql shell as follows:
CREATE DATABASE name;
CREATE TABLE example (id PRIMARY KEY)

But I'm not sure if either was actually created. They don't appear in pgadmin. The bit of text that appears at the start of the line before you type (is there a name for this?) seems to change from Server [localhost] to Database [postgres] and then Port [5432] as I run these two lines. Another possible problem is that I can't hit enter to specify a series of columns because it just immediately runs the code, and shift+enter doesn't change this.

Running '\d', I get list of 'ignored' arguments and the error: 'could not translate host name 'CREATE' to address: Unknown host.' This may mean I need to specify a 'host' first, but I'm not sure how I would do this, or what the difference is between a host and a server.

Apologies for asking such a simple question, but I'm having difficulty getting off the ground and have struggled to follow other resources.

Many thanks

Comment: That is what the docs are for [pgAdmin](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/7.1/index.html). Assuming you got `pgAdmin` by installing Postgres from here [EDB download](https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads) then the server is already setup. To create a database read this [Database dialog](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/7.1/database_dialog.html).

Comment: "The bit of text that appears at the start of the line before you type (is there a name for this?)"  Those are called "prompts".  It sounds like you are running the windows wrapper around psql, which is prompting you for what settings you want to use to connect, and offering you defaults in brackets.  But apparently you are trying to enter commands at those prompts, before you even have established the connection and started up psql proper.  That is the wrong place to enter commands.